# Azure China: Change tracking is not supported

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-china

I am trying to backup Azure china OneDrive using Graph API. I am able to authenticate, enumerate the items. But the request "https://microsoftgraph.chinacloudapi.cn/v1.0/drives/drive-ID-value/root/delta" fails with the following error:

"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Unsupported request: Change tracking is not supported against 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'."

From the error, it looks like Azure China doesn't support delta queries. But the following page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments#supported-features lists delta query as a supported feature.

Please let me know if anyone has seen such an issue.

Comment: You may get more clarity by contacting Azure support, as they can answer your question about their offerings in their China region more directly.

Comment: What if you use the `/beta` endpoint?

Comment: Please check the above documentation it talks about that "Limited support for Exchange and OneDrive services only" and i think due to that you're getting the above issue for delta query.

Comment: Have raised this with MSFT support.

Comment: @user13260866 Any further findings on this one?